# Firebase Initialization Error: App Default not created and App Default already exists

Tags: firebase, next.js

I have already asked this question before and the solution was to restart my server. I'm using the same code again but this time server restart doesn't help.

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
};

if(!firebase.app.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();


export {db, auth, provider};
```

Entire error from console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRqD3.png .

If I initialize it out of if statement it gives me and error that default app already exists;  tried placing both in if else:

```
if(!firebase.app.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else{
    firebase.app();
}
```

but then it goes back to "No Firebase App Default has been created".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `firebase.apps.length` (plural), not `firebase.app.length` (singular). Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#apps

Comment: oh geez, I can't believe I haven't noticed that. Thank you very much Frank ♥